# How do I plot a line in Matlab for every column in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, datetime, for-loop, plot, time-series

I have a matrix that is organized row-wise as follows:

```
Row 1: Year (e.g., 2004)
Row 2: Month (e.g., 6)
Row 3: Discharge (e.g., 90 m3/s)
```

I have 23 columns total (3x23 matrix). I want to plot all columns that are associated with each year (e.g., columns 1-4 correspond to data collected for the year 2004) as a single line. How do I find and plot all columns for a given year? Ultimately, I want to plot each year of data (over multiple columns) as lines on the same plot (maybe best done as a for loop?).

Or, is it better to combine rows 1 and 2 (year and month) into Matlab time and then plot discharge for each year that way? If so, how would I write this in Matlab?

A sample of the data and its organization is as follows:

```
2004    2004    2004    2004    2005    2005
6       7       8       9       5       6
90.97   591.88  515.09  1.83    1.41    209.07
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%% For this example, I plotted month against discharge - change as needed

%% Your sample data

```
a = [2004,2004,2004,2004,2005,2005;
6,7,8,9,5,6;
90.97,591.88,515.09,1.83,1.41,209.07];
```

%% Get the years represented

```
years_represented = unique(a(1,:));
```

%% Get the number of years represented

```
num_of_years = length(years_represented);
```

%% Use loop to get data for each year and plot (customize as needed).

```
for idx = 1:num_of_years

curr_year = years_represented(idx);    % current year

curr_year_idx = a(1,:) == curr_year;   % columns of current year

curr_year_data = a(:,curr_year_idx);   % current year data

plot(curr_year_data(2,:),curr_year_data(3,:)); % plot current year data 

hold on 

end

xlabel('Month')         % X-axis label
ylabel('Discharge')     % Y-axis label
hold off
```